# How to overwrite rows in the database when passing values from Console Application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq, console-application

I am currently working on a tool that scrapes some XML files from a directory and passes the values to the database afterward. Every time I run the code, these values will stack up in the database and duplicates appear. These files might change, so the code will be run occasionally to keep the database updated, hence I need to come up with a code that completes the following conditions:

1. If values scraped from the XML files are different from the one in the database, add a new row.
2. If the values scraped from the XML files are the same from the database, overwrite those from the database.
3. If values in the database were not overwritten, flag them as outdated. (put value 1 or 0 in a column named "Flagged")

Now that I've made a short summary of what I think needs to be done, we can take a look at the code.

```
foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\GS1").GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTimeUtc))
{

    try
    {

        var xDocument = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
        foreach (XElement XE in xDocument.Descendants())
        {
            XE.Name = XE.Name.LocalName;
            XE.ReplaceAttributes((from xattrib in XE.Attributes().Where(xa => !xa.IsNamespaceDeclaration) select new XAttribute(xattrib.Name.LocalName, xattrib.Value)));
        }
        var tradeItems = xDocument.Descendants().Where(f => f.Name == "tradeItem");
        foreach (var tradeItem in tradeItems)
        {

            if (tradeItem.Elements().Any(f => f.Name == "isTradeItemAConsumerUnit" && bool.Parse(f.Value)))
            {
                ...
                var gtin = tradeItem.Elements().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "gtin")?.Value?.Trim();
                var ingredients = tradeItem.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "ingredientStatement")?.Value?.Trim();
                var tradeMarket = tradeItem.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "tradeItemMarketingMessage")?.Value?.Trim();
```

So the above code describes pretty much how I am actually grabbing these values that I want to pass to the database afterward. Some code was omitted but I wanted to include only the most relevant stuff.

Then I call the `Save()` method which is the following:

```
private static void Save(FileInfo file, string gtin, string brandName, string partyName, string descriptionShort, string functionalName, string netContent, string fileName, string extension, byte[] image, string angle, DateTime? qualificationDate, string ingredients, DataTable nutritionFacts, string tradeMarket, string imageLink)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = xxxxxxxxx; Initial Catalog = dinkurv_dev; Persist Security Info = False; User ID = radu; Password =xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"))
                {
                    ...
                    conn.Execute("INSERT INTO GS1MarketingInformation VALUES (@gtin, @tradeMarket)", new { gtin, tradeMarket });
                    conn.Execute("IF EXISTS(SELECT * from GS1IngredientInformation WHERE GTIN=@gtin) UPDATE GS1IngredientInformation SET GTIN=@gtin, @Ingredient_Information=@ingredients" +
                                 "ELSE INSERT INTO GS1IngredientInformation VALUES (@gtin, @tradeMarket)", new { gtin, ingredients });
                    break;
                }
            }   
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

So as you can see above, in the Save method I have these two rows:

`conn.Execute("INSERT INTO GS1MarketingInformation VALUES (@gtin, @tradeMarket)", new { gtin, tradeMarket });` which inserts everything into the database, doesn't take into consideration the already existent values. Therefore I came up with the second row:

```
conn.Execute("IF EXISTS(SELECT * from GS1IngredientInformation WHERE GTIN=@gtin) UPDATE GS1IngredientInformation SET GTIN=@gtin, @Ingredient_Information=@ingredients" +
"ELSE INSERT INTO GS1IngredientInformation VALUES (@gtin, @tradeMarket)", new { gtin, ingredients });
```

which is an attempt of overwriting stuff that's already in the database while adding new values if there are not already existent there. However, though, the second code doesn't really work properly. From what I've seen, it just drops every row and then replaces it with another set of values.

In conclusion: How can I re-write the code above so that it matches the 3 conditions I talked about? I feel like I am quite close to achieving the overwrite thing but my limited SQL knowledge is kind of dragging me backwards.

Comment: The first thing I can see is that your update statement is updating every row of the table. You would likely need to put in a where clause to only update the rows you want to be updated. E.g. UPDATE Table SET Row1 = 'fake value' WHERE id = 1 will update only the rows in the database table that have a value of 1 in the id column

Comment: I highly suggest you change the credentials of the database. Sharing credentials on a public website basically means the data isn't yours anymore; anyone can change the data given the correct permissions.

Comment: Other than that you should take closer look at MERGE statement which will allow you to do INSERT and UPDATE in one statement.

Comment: @Caramiriel woah, I missed out that piece of code. Thanks for editing it out. Also, thanks for your other input lads, I will be looking into your answers and see if I can sort it out.